# What is stored in the "/var/lib/dpkg/updates" folder?

Tags: filesystem, dpkg

I've seen some folks have errors relating to files in `/var/lib/dpkg/updates`. All I can find about the directory is that the files in it are numbered `0000`, `0001` etc. and that the error messages often mention "trouble parsing one of the files".

`/var/lib/dpkg/updates` folder is empty on my system, so I can't see what's in the files. I've not been able to find information about what is stored in this directory, only many forum posts and bug reports mentioning the directory.

So, what is this directory for?

Comment: Just my luck... the directory is empty on my system too :(

Comment: It seems _something_ is kept there temporarily during upgrades. But I'm not brave enough to stop an upgrade midway to find out what's there.  ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the update `dpkg` stores status of the installation/update there. This is how an incomplete installation process can be detected and decided what are the next packages going to be installed, So that the system can ask to use `dpkg-configure -a` if anything happens before completing installation or update.

Normally after a successful installation, the directory should be empty.

Comment: So it's sort of a log that dpkg can use to pick up where it left off. Very smart, but I feel sorry for the guy who had to code it.  ;-)  Thanks!