# dpkg: error: cannot scan updates directory `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/'

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I want to install a package in Ubuntu 14.04, but every time I run the `./configure` command it gives me this error:

```
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 35%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 70%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: error: cannot scan updates directory `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/': No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

Comment: DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04, DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty,DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS", ID_LIKE=debian

Comment: `dpkg` is complaining that it can't find is directory `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/` where it uses that directory to stores status of the installation/update. Question, what did you do before, that causes this error? did you delete anything from the directory `/var/lib/dpkg/`?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have done something terrible to the directory `/var/lib/dpkg` refer to this posts here to know more about `dpkg` [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867285/i-need-to-run-a-script-that-might-break-apt-get-database-what-should-i-backup/867420#867420) and [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527/what-is-stored-in-the-var-lib-dpkg-updates-folder)

Back to your problem, to solve the problem, you should try doing the following,

First Option

Return the dir `status` only if it was the one messed up.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install the packages as normal

Second Option(This solution assume you have completely messed up with `/var/lib/dpkg`

Restore a backup of `/dpkg/status/`  from `/var/backups/` or `/var/lib/dpkg/` since `status` holds the database of `dpkg`,you will probably be able to restore the database and everything will turn back to normal.

In the dir `/var/backups/` you will be having a folder like `dpkg.status.0` ,and compressed file `dpkg.status.1` ,`dpkg.status.2` etc,this are the backups we are targeting,we are going to use backup `dpkg.status.0` to restore,do the following:

Since you already have dir `/var/lib/dpkg`
Copy the backup to that dir

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/
```

NOTE:The latest backup is `dpkg.status.0` file,but If you want to backup from the archive file i.e. `dpkg.status.#.gz` do

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.#.gz /var/lib/dpkg/

gunzip -d /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.#.gz
```

Then rename `dpkg.status.#` to `status` i.e. `dpkg.status.0`

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then create the folder `update`

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/update
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

After that you can install the softwares as normal!

Comment: I'm curious if `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` is also a backup option. Also note there are a total of four `/var/lib/dpkg/*-old` files.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ,Yes ,there are also backups ,the difference is, completely updated backups are in `/var/backups/` probably the latest `status.0` file.

Answer (score 1):

What does this mean?

Means your `dpkg` configuration has got messed up somehow. The package management system has a database which has all information on what packages , system tools or software in general are installed in the system, and when it gets damaged problems like this appear.

What needs to be done?

First, check for issues with PPAs as mentioned in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Secondly, try the advice here: [Package system is broken, multiple errors, dpkg cannot process libc6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322084/package-system-is-broken)

Step 3: Try running these commands as root

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
```

If nothing works, you might have to take a back-up and re-install Ubuntu

OR

Hack it as mentioned in [Problem installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220649/problem-installing-packages/485293#485293)

Clean, Update and Dist upgrade apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If terminal prompts with questions like Y / N etc... always opt for the default option highlighted in caps; most probably it would be N. Until and unless you are really sure of what you are doing

[Stack Overflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997015/e-cannot-get-debconf-version-is-debconf-installed)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

if this command (`sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` doesn't work, then try the three following commands)

```
sudo killall apt-get
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then try below

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```